# indexeddb getting last added record non-alphabetically

Tags: indexeddb

If i have data in indexeddb in format {name:'example1'} with keypath - name and everything is ordered alphabetically, how can i get last added record not alphabetically?

this is my init for database

```
 var openRequest = indexedDB.open("database",1);
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    var thisDB = e.target.result;

    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("add")) {
        var store = thisDB.createObjectStore("add",{keyPath: 'name'});
    }
    if(!thisDB.objectStoreNames.contains("del")) {
        var store = thisDB.createObjectStore("del",{keyPath: 'name'});
    }

}

openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("running onsuccess");
    db = e.target.result;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["add"],"readonly");
    var store = transaction.objectStore("add");
...
```

and this is getting the last item(which is wrong - it takes last records starting with 'z' letter):

```
            var openRequest = indexedDB.open('database');
            var type = true;

            openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
                db = e.target.result;
                if(type) {
                    var transaction = db.transaction(msg.type,"readwrite");
                    var store = transaction.objectStore(msg.type);
                    var cursorRequest = store.openCursor(null,"prev");
                    cursorRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
                      var result = e.target.result;
                      if(result) {
                        var key_t = result.key;
                        var del_request = result.delete();
                        del_request.onsuccess = function() {
                          console.log('Deleted '+key_t);
                        };
                      } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways:

1) store a date created property per object. create an index on this property. then open a cursor with prev on this index.

2) store objects using a basic id. create an index on name. when you want to load objects ordered by name, use the name index. when you want to load the last inserted object, just open a cursor on the object store itself, which will use natural order (insertion order).